# How to return only JSON string for ajax requests [disable view]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter. I'm trying to integrate Extjs to Codeigniter. So when i make Ajax request the server should return only JSON string but instead server returns view [default] view along with the JSON string. Is it possible to disable view and return only data in codeignter. I have used zend framework before where i could disable view for ajax requests

I have tried some suggestions like in
[jQuery and CodeIgniter AJAX with JSON not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531273/jquery-and-codeigniter-ajax-with-json-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, at the end off the function, try:

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller: `die(json_encode($data_array));`

It's not smart way doing that, but works perfect.