# Code Igniter helper for creating drop down boxes

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am very new to code igniter and i get the very basics of how it works, i've been asked to write a helper for which i have never done, the result is for the helper to be called and it populate drop down boxes or a box with different fields and once selected the next box dynamically change based on what was selected previously. in this instance selecting a work industry then from that the next selection would be their job inside that industry.

i have no idea how to go about this the few tutorials i found are quite straight forward in having dropdown boxes based on hard coded text.

apologies but i am new to code igniter and the code bellow was given to me to work on and im not a fan of working with code ive not built myself so apologies if names dont match up

Helper file

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('get_industry')) {
    function get_industry() {

        // function code to go here

    }
}

if (!function_exists('get_occupation')) {
    function get_occupation() {

        // function code to go here

    }
}

if (!function_exists('get_hmrc')) {
    function get_() {

        // function code to go here

    }
}
```

model

```
?php

class m_sectors extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_industry(){
        $this -> db -> distinct() -> select('industry') -> from('frontend_sectors');
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
        return $query -> result();
    }

    public function get_titles($sector){

    }



}
?>
```

controller

```
<?php

class sectors extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model('m_sectors');
    }

    function index(){
        print_r($this -> m_sectors -> get_industry());
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you cant call models from the helper files. They are simple functions and don't deal with the backend. You need to create a library for it.

Comment: @Nil'z You're wrong, You can call anything You need. `get_instance()` will return CI object, so You can use it in helper `get_instance()->load->model('mymodel'); get_instance()->mymodel->myfunction();`

Comment: I would do this by using json_encode to return results from the controller to the view in JSON based on the previous selection (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531273/jquery-and-codeigniter-ajax-with-json-not-working) and you would use jQuery AJAX to send requests to the relevant controller. I.e. you would have a method in the Controller that queries the model with the Industry ID and returns the relevant job titles returned from the model in that industry.